# Getting the wrong Thevenin equivalent resistor

Tags: thevenin

Its been a while since last time I worked with circuits.

Im trying to find the Thevenin equivalent resistor to this circuit.

[image]

This is how I tried solving it.

[image]

The correct answer according to the solutions manual is 3 ohms. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the question? Does it specify the Thevenin resistor as seen between certain terminals? Also consider that sometimes solutions manuals are simply wrong.

Comment: I don't see how it can be 3 from any point. Are you sure you are reading the anser to the right question?

Comment: Maybe the problem is to find the equivalent resistance of the circuit seen by the side of the (input) voltage source? Then it really is (about) 3 ohms.

Comment: The solution is probably wrong. How do I find the Thevenin equivalent voltage source? The answer should be 125V. I dont know how to do it. I tried with node voltage but I dont know how to do node voltage when I have a resistor (24 ohms) and a current source (3A) in the same branch. I get (v1-100v)/24ohms + v1/2 ohms but dont know what to do with the 24 ohms resistor and the 3A current source. also tried with the mesh current method, but I havent learned to do mesh current method with a current source.

Comment: @mangekyou What is the point of the label called \$v_1\$? (And, I suppose, \$v_2\$?) Are you trying to find what \$R_\text{L}\$ "sees" looking into the "black box" of the rest of the circuit? Or what the \$100\:\text{V}\$ source "sees" with (or without) \$R_\text{L}\$ attached? Is the Thevenin voltage you want the same thing as \$v_2\$?

Comment: I dont know. The exact wording is: Draw a Thevenin equivalent circuit up until RL. In my equation I wrote (v1-100v)/24 ohms. That was I typo. I meant to write (v1-100v)/2 ohms.

Comment: @mangekyou Thanks. That helps. That, plus your comment about 125 V. I'll write something up that covers this several ways. It motivates me that you've addressed questions here and I believe that you really are trying to understand things. So I'll write an answer that will cover this topic several different ways. (Even if some of my answer seems out of reach at first, I believe you will soon encounter them.)

Comment: @mangekyou: it doesn't make sense to present a circuit and ask for its equivalent circuit (or its Thevenin euivalent resistance) **unless it is clear  which two terminals are the interface**. I guess that's what jonk was trying to clearify. If the terminal are the ones at \$R_L\$  and \$R_L\$ is not included in the circuit whose equqivalent you are looking for then you need to state that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to proceed on the problem. Your circuit example can be addressed by what's usually learned early -- before mesh or nodal analysis. So I'll start with the basic Thevenin to Norton and Norton to Thevenin conversions. Let's start.

### Step 1

Perform a Thevenin to Norton conversion on the left-side two components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXhVjw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think you can see how this was achieved, if you are at all familiar with this transformation.

### Step 2

Take the two resistors in parallel and combine them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUSWfr.png)</sup>

Again, this is pretty basic and I'm sure you've already become familiar with this.

### Step 3

Perform a Norton to Thevenin conversion on the left-side two components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQTVht.png)</sup>

Again, I think you are familiar with this conversion.

### Step 4

Take the two resistors in series and combine them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6b9bU.png)</sup>

### Step 5

Perform a Thevenin to Norton conversion on the left-side two components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feQLKC.png)</sup>

### Step 6

Combine the current sources:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmApwi.png)</sup>

### Step 7

At this point, just convert back to Thevenin. Here you will get \$V_\text{TH}=125\:\text{V}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}=25\:\Omega\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8iuAG.png)</sup>

---

Another approach is to perform nodal analysis and later inject a \$1\:\text{A}\$ source. So, for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI6v9B.png)</sup>

The nodal equations are:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{X}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{24\:\Omega}&=\frac{100\:\text{V}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{TH}}{24\:\Omega}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{TH}}{24\:\Omega}&=\frac{V_\text{X}}{24\:\Omega}+3\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

Which solve out as: \$V_\text{TH}=125\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_\text{X}=53\:\text{V}\$.

Now, inject \$1\:\text{A}\$ into the (+) node. The new nodal equations are:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{X}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{24\:\Omega}&=\frac{100\:\text{V}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_\text{TH}}{24\:\Omega}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{TH}}{24\:\Omega}&=\frac{V_\text{X}}{24\:\Omega}+3\:\text{A}+1\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

And the new results are: \$V_\text{TH}=150\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_\text{X}=54\:\text{V}\$.

This means that \$R_\text{TH}=\frac{150\:\text{V}-125\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{A}-0\:\text{A}}=25\:\Omega\$.

So, \$V_\text{TH}=125\:\text{V}\$ from the open-circuit case and then \$R_\text{TH}=25\:\Omega\$, as derived from changes due to the injection of a \$1\:\text{A}\$ current. So the results using nodal analysis confirm the multi-step process used earlier here.

Answer (score -1):

We can easily find VTH if we first apply the superposition principle to calculate V1 = 50 + 3 = 53 V... then add the voltage drop of 72 V across the 24 ohm resistor. Thus VTH = 53 + 72 = 125 V.

If we still try to obtain the wrong(?) solution of 3 ohms (as a kind of mental excersise), we can look at this circuit from a different perspective. Imagine the voltage source of 100 V is the load and the rest of the circuit to the right is the source. Then RTH = 3.968 ohms what is close to the 3 ohms of the answer.